# Is a 2GB RAM difference that important

Tags: memory

I have this game that requires a minimum of 6GB of RAM but the computer that I'm currently playing on has 4GB of RAM would that really impact how the game loads or not (This isn't my computer, my computer has 16GB). I'm not a person who's "oh this HAS to run a minimum of 60FPS or else I won't play it" I'm fine if the game at least runs at 30FPS. Btw the game is "Rise of The Tomb Raider"

Comment: No, its a school computer and I don't want to wait for it to download then find out it won't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer makes recommendations and requirements for a reason: usually, that reason is because the program either cannot function at all on a computer that does not meet the specifications, or it will function so poorly as to reflect badly on the manufacturer. Further, if you do not run the program on a computer that meets the recommendation, you will get no support from the manufacturer beyond instructions to upgrade the computer to meet the specifications.

Comment: I have a computer that can run the game just fine and has 16GB RAM but I was just wondering if the RAM would really make a difference on the other computer I was going to play it on

Comment: @DoomedSpace - your only real option is to try it and decide based on your experience. Based on what I said above, _it will make a difference, and will probably not perform in a satisfactory manner_.

Answer (score -1):

2 GB does make a difference for smoothness of gameplay. Less RAM means it is more likely to stutter. There will be minimal FPS improvements.

To conclude, yes you can play Tomb Raider but expect the occasional stutter. Otherwise it is perfectly playable.